# Strange trailing character received from res.end

Tags: node.js, encoding

Here's the backend code:

```
res.statusCode = 400
res.setHeader 'Content-Type', 'text/plain'
res.end 'Invalid API endpoint.'
```

When I curl it from terminal, I get:

```
Invalid API endpoint.%
```

the "%" sign shows up with inverted colors.

Why is that "%" sign there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This marks a partial line, since the response send does not have a trailing newline.  From

```
man zshoptions
```

> ```
>     PROMPT_SP <D>
>           Attempt  to  preserve  a partial line (i.e. a line that did not
>           end with a newline) that would otherwise be covered up  by  the
>           command prompt due to the PROMPT_CR option.  This works by out‐
>           putting some cursor-control characters, including a  series  of
>           spaces,  that  should  make  the terminal wrap to the next line
>           when a partial line is present (note that this is only success‐
>           ful if your terminal has automatic margins, which is typical).
> ```

```
          When  a  partial  line is preserved, by default you will see an
          inverse+bold character at the end of the partial line:   a  "%"
          for a normal user or a "#" for root.  If set, the shell parame‐
          ter PROMPT_EOL_MARK can be used to customize  how  the  end  of
          partial lines are shown.

          NOTE:  if the PROMPT_CR option is not set, enabling this option
          will have no effect.  This option is on by default.
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, should have append a trailing newline in text/plain responses?

Comment: That depends entirely on how it will be used.

Comment: Right now I just want to send a simple plain text message for humans to read, like "Invalid API endpoint.".

Comment: I shouldn't hurt, but you should test with whatever client programs will be used.